# Split a data frame into six equal parts based on number of rows without knowing the number of rows - pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df as shown below.

df:

```
ID   Job   Salary
1    A     100
2    B     200
3    B     20
4    C     150
5    A     500
6    A     600
7    A     200
8    B     150
9    C     110
10   B     200
11   B     220
12   A     150
13   C     20
14   B     50
```

I would like to split the df into 6 equal parts based on the number of rows.
Expected Output
df1:

```
ID   Job   Salary
1    A     100
2    B     200
3    B     20
```

df2:

```
ID   Job   Salary
4    C     150
5    A     500
6    A     600
```

df3:

```
ID   Job   Salary
7    A     200
8    B     150
```

df4:

```
ID   Job   Salary
9    C     110
10   B     200
```

df5:

```
ID   Job   Salary
11   B     220
12   A     150
```

df6:

```
ID   Job   Salary
13   C     20
14   B     50
```

Note: Since there are 14 rows first two dfs can have 3 rows and the remaining 4 dfs should have 2 rows.

And I would like to save all dfs as csv dynamically

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [**`np.array_split()`**](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html):

```py
dfs = np.array_split(df, 6)

for index, df in enumerate(dfs):
    df.to_csv(f'df{index+1}.csv')
```

```py
>>> print(dfs)

[   ID Job  Salary
 0   1   A     100
 1   2   B     200
 2   3   B      20,

    ID Job  Salary
 3   4   C     150
 4   5   A     500
 5   6   A     600,

    ID Job  Salary
 6   7   A     200
 7   8   B     150,

    ID Job  Salary
 8   9   C     110
 9  10   B     200,

     ID Job  Salary
 10  11   B     220
 11  12   A     150,

     ID Job  Salary
 12  13   C      20
 13  14   B      50]
```