# Split dataftame on parts keeping equal proportions of the column's content

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm

I have dataframe with 2 columns and 150k rows: date and target (0 or 1), sorted by date.
How can I split it on parts, keeping equal proportions 0 and 1 in every part.
Like this:

```
date     target             part 1           part 2 
01.2000    0                01.2000    0     02.2000    1
01.2000    1        -->>    01.2000    1     02.2000    0
02.2000    1                 (50%)             (50%)
02.2000    0
```

to be able to change the number of parts.
And need to save the starting sort. Dates is parts shood be like 01.2000 01.2000 and 02.2000 02.2000. Not 01.2000 02. 2000, 02.2000 01 2000.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/67356495/8353711

Comment: Try this, `dfs = np.array_split(df, 2)`

Comment: @shaikmoeed - How is that keeping equal proportions of 0 and 1?

Comment: @shaikmoeed it will split on the same parts.  But if targets will be 1 0 1 0 0 0 , and 2 parts, id will not be the same proportions.

Comment: @not_speshal Right, it will just split the array in two equal parts, but not the stratified split as expected by OP.

Comment: @Alexandr Got you, I used `train_test_split`, to find the stratified split as you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `np.array_split` on individual targets and then `concat`:

```
results = [pd.concat([z,o]) for (z,o) in zip(np.array_split(df[df["target"].eq(0)],2), 
                                             np.array_split(df[df["target"].eq(1)],2)
                                             )]
```

Comment: it will not save sorting. If after this move I will concat 2 dataframes, i will not get the starting sort. Right?

Comment: The results already include the `concat`. How do you expect to keep the order AND proportion same?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [train_test_split](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html#sklearn-model-selection-train-test-split),

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

part1, part2 = train_test_split(df, 
                                test_size=0.5, 
                                stratify=df['target'], 
                                random_state=42)
# or
# *parts = train_test_split(df, 
                            test_size=0.5, 
                            stratify=df['target'], 
                            random_state=42)
# parts will be list of 2 dataframes
```

Comment: Yes, it will take equal proportions, but it will not save the start sort. Right?

Comment: @Alexandr Yes, the order will change, but you can do `.sort_values` on parts to maintain ascending or descending order. But, why it is required?

Comment: it is necessary that the time intervals be parsed in order.

Comment: @Alexandr, if your dataframe is already sorted then `not_speshal's` [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76977910/8353711) will work.

Answer (score 0):

Sort by `target`.

```
date     target
01.2000    0
02.2000    0
01.2000    1
02.2000    1
```

From here you have two options: reset your index and use that, or create a column of incrementing integers. I will use the index.

```
idx   date     target
0     01.2000    0
1     02.2000    0
2     01.2000    1
3     02.2000    1
```

Split the index by evens and odds. Your `target` should be in equal proportions in the two groups (with the exception of an odd number of rows, of course).

```py
races = ...
races = races.sort_values("target", ignore_index=True)

groups = [
    races[races.index % 2],
    races[~(races.index % 2)],
]
```

First DataFrame:

```
idx   date     target
1     02.2000    0
3     02.2000    1
```

Second DataFrame:

```
idx   date     target
0     01.2000    0
2     01.2000    1
```

Comment: i'll not get the starting sort, if i'll concat that dataframes after this moves

Comment: Ah, didn't realize that. So don't reset the index. Create a new column instead and sort/filter on that. Once you finish doing whatever you need the two parts for, `pd.concat` and sort by the index (it was untouched).